# A few users and subuid/subgid mapping

Tags: lxc, lxd, uid

I cannot get my head around the [userns-idmap](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/userns-idmap/) mapping ie with [sub{uid,gid}](https://man.archlinux.org/man/subuid.5) mapping stuff.

Here's what I have:

```
# lxc launch images:ubuntu/22.04 c1
# lxc config device add c1 home disk source=/home/user3/ path=/home/user3
# lxc config device add c1 shared disk source=/mnt/shared path=/mnt/shared
```

Then I added a user and group to the container:

```
# lxc exec c1 bash
# groupadd -g 1003 user3
# groupadd -g 1004 shared
# useradd -u 1003 -g 1003 -G shared user3
```

- The user `user3` has the uid `1003` on the host and belongs to the group `shared` (as well as its own)
- The group `shared` has the gid of `1004`

Here's my `sub{uid,gid}`:

```
sudo tee /etc/sub{uid,gid} <<EOF
root:1000:65536
user0:100000:65536
user1:100001:65536
user2:100002:65536
user3:100003:65536
EOF

sudo tee -a /etc/subgid <<EOF
shared:100004:1
EOF
```

I want to map `user3`'s uid `1003` and gid `1003` into the container. I also want to map `shared` which is `1004` on the host into the container.

1. Is my `/etc/sub{uid,gid}` correct?
2. What do i need for the `raw.idmap` command?
3. I want to make a `c2` container which has home directories for `user0-3` mapped through.

I tried:

```
# printf 'both 1003 1003\ngid 1004 1\n' | lxc config set c1 raw.lxc -
```

to begin with, but was getting the error:

> ERROR    conf - ../src/lxc/conf.c:lxc_map_ids:3672 - newuidmap failed to write mapping "newuidmap: uid range [1001-1002) -> [100003-100004) not allowed": newuidmap 22185 0 1000 1001 1001 10000
>
> ERROR    start - ../src/lxc/start.c:lxc_spawn:1791 - Failed to set up id mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution to this.

I needed:

```
cat /etc/subuid
root:1000:1
root:1001:1
root:1002:1
root:1003:1
root:100000:65536
lxd:100000:65536
```

```
$ cat /etc/subgid
root:1000:1
root:1001:1
root:1002:1
root:1003:1
root:1004:1
root:100000:65536
lxd:100000:65536
```

The reason it had to be `root` was because because LXD launches LXC containers as the host's root user. The containers themselves are still unprivileged (in that root inside the container isn't root on the host).

Further it was needed to also add an entry to `/etc/lxc/default.conf` of:

```
lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 1000
lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 1000
lxc.idmap = u 1000 1000 1
lxc.idmap = g 1000 1000 1
lxc.idmap = u 1001 101001 0
lxc.idmap = g 1001 101001 0
lxc.idmap = u 1001 1001 1
lxc.idmap = g 1001 1001 1
lxc.idmap = u 1002 101002 0
lxc.idmap = g 1002 101002 0
lxc.idmap = u 1002 1002 1
lxc.idmap = g 1002 1002 1
lxc.idmap = u 1003 101003 0
lxc.idmap = g 1003 101003 0
lxc.idmap = u 1003 1003 1
lxc.idmap = g 1003 1003 1
lxc.idmap = u 1004 101004 64532
lxc.idmap = g 1004 1004 1
lxc.idmap = g 1005 101005 64532
```

For generating this I found [`proxmox-lxc-idmapper`](https://github.com/ddimick/proxmox-lxc-idmapper) which helped me generate the correct `lxc.idmap`.

Note though the tool is not without bugs, so you should check the output carefully, to make sure it's actually what you want.

Comment: Amazing, this script help me so much, I think I now even understand what I did wrong all this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your subuid definitions are overlapping, which is not allowed.

```
user0:100000:65536
```

This means user0 gets `100000` to `165535`. This also means that the next user has to start at `165536`.

```
user1:165536:65536
```

The next gets

```
user2:231072:65536
```

and so on.

Comment: What would the `raw.idmap` look like then for passing in `user2` (in your example) and the `shared` group?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with shared subuids and I don't know what you mean by `raw.idmap`.

Comment: It's a part of [custom-idmaps](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/userns-idmap/#custom-idmaps). Basically trying to do [Add a shared host directory to an LXC/LXD container (read-write mode)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-or-mount-directory-in-lxd-linux-container/)

Comment: "Your subuid definitions are overlapping, which is not allowed."  citation needed? This claim is thrown around a lot but I'm not sure where the supposed restriction comes from.

The uid_map and gid_map associated with an individual process are certainly not allowed to overlap as documented in user_namespaces(7), but this is separate to which users are allowed to use a subuid/gid range. subuid(5)/subgid(5) don't mention overlapping IDs

Comment: "not allowed" might have been a bit harsh. Better would be "should not overlap, as it leads to  shared UIDs on the filesystem, which leads to security issues as users are able to read/write files of other users, which is exactly what the subuid/guid system is supposed to prevent."